# Rename Queue name before initialization in spring amqp

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a peculiar requirement in spring amqp to rename exchange and queue at runtime before loading its properties from beans.xml 
Eg My queue name is defined in beans.xml as test

```
  <bean id="test"
        class="testclass">
        <constructor-arg name="exchange" ref="directExchange" />
        <constructor-arg name="routingKey" value="test" />
        <constructor-arg name="queue" value="test" />
     </bean>
```

But the requirement is  before creation of the test queue in rabbit server is there any way in spring amqp to rename the queue to abc.test etc .

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are creating queues? That will help us determine if they can be modified. But just an FYI on how we do it; We configure the properties(of a queue) as server properties and read them from the server configuration itself. In that way you keep the code away from configuration. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me which goal you are aiming, but looks like `<context:property-placeholder>` and `profiles` support are for you.

Please, refer to Spring Framework [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) for more information.